# QT platform plugin "windows"

Tags: c++, qt

So I am working on my Diploma Thesis, and so far everything went fine.

So this week I installed Win8.1 on my PC and installed QT, implemented some things and wanted to send the release version of my program to my company. 
I compiled the hole thing, copied it to my release folder and i got an error.

"This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform    plugin "windows"."

I googled and found out that I have add a folder named "platforms". Said and done. Same error.  I also tried to copy the hole plugins folder to my release folder. Same error.
I really need help because my boss isn't happy about giving in work too late.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Add your directory structure; Which compiler do you use? E.g. when using MSVC, the target computer will need the MSVC runtime installed. Check with Dependency Walker what's missing. Make sure you read https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html

Comment: My directory structure: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-22196593/folder.png.html
I'm using MinGW 32bit as compiler.

Comment: qwindows.dll should be placed in the platforms directory.

Comment: It is in platforms, I just tried to copy it everywhere that this thing starts working.. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying Qt 5 App on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185974/deploying-qt-5-app-on-windows)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the Problem!

Previously i used the dll's from my old QT installation. I just copied the ones from the new Installtion into a folder and the exe. I don't even need the qwindow.dll now. 
BUT! I works now... :)

Is there a way, that I create my own DLL, just for my Application?

But still thanks for your help!

Comment: This answer is completely useless to future visitors. Please take the time to actually describe what the problem was (assuming that you cared enough to find out), and why the proposed solution solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have "qminimal.dll" placed in your platforms directory?

Edit:
Sorry, "qminimal.dll" was not displayed in my previous post.

Comment: If your app is using any additional drivers (plugins) like SQL or something, the corresponding dll has to be placed in "plugins" folder.

Comment: Maybe you could also post a screenshot of dependency walker. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256872/en-us