# Do I use SVG image direct or render?

Tags: qt, svg, qml

I have got an svg file (this is a world map image). SVG file (world map) is providing path tags and d attributes for country coordinates . When I click on the country, I want to get clicked country name. So, should I use svg file with `Image` (direct) for this job?
Like this:

```
Image {
  id: worldMap
  anchors.fill: parent
  source: 'qrc:/world_map.svg'
}
```

Or should I render svg file for this job? If answer is render svg, so how can I draw svg file with `QML` without C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QML doesn't show svg images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242420/qml-doesnt-show-svg-images)

Comment: @eyllanesc: I don't see the connection between your link and that question besides that both are correctly asigned the tag [qml] and [svg].