# Mixed QML/C++ app wont display anything after deployment

Tags: c++, qt, qml

What could be the reason that my QML/C++ app will not display anything after deploying it with `windeployqt`?

The app displays normally on task manager, and throws no errors.

Comment: Are the QML files included in the resources or are they standalone files? One guess would be that the application can not find the QML files to display anything after deployment.

Comment: I have all my qml files in a resource file of course. Thats what I thought too, but it should be able to find them since they correctly appear on my project tree under the resource file.

Comment: Is the application deployed on another machine (maybe without installed Qt) and not running correctly or does the application even not run on the development machine after deployment?

Comment: Im still on the development machine actually. Just wanted to test

Comment: Are you sure that there are no errors? Have you run it through [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896647.aspx)? I would also look to QML files missing, as @AlexanderGiesler said. From memory there's some extra option you have to pass there to get all of the QML stuff deployed.

Comment: No the project emits no message whatsoever. Just sits there quietly.  Also I am not aware of any supplementary option for qml, I will do a search though.

Comment: Maybe check this post here with a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185974/deploying-qt-5-app-on-windows

Comment: Unfortunately it was not as simple for me as just copying the qml folder to my build directory. Not to mention that I dont even get any errors.

Comment: I solved it, but it was in the most unhelpful way. I simply copied everything and deleted all except from what the program was using. This makes the question useless I believe since there is nothing to be learned. Please advice on if I should delete it or not.

Comment: I would add the solution to the question and mark it as solved. Maybe some day someone struggles with the same issue and can find one possible solution here, sparing him/her multiple hours of trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was to simply copy all files from your

```
<qtversion>/<comp_verson>/plugins
<qtversion>/<comp_verson>/bin
<qtversion>/<comp_verson>/qml
```

to where you executable is, and then while having your app open deleting everything. What it is used, and therefore needed will stay.

Comment: It's worth pointing out your comment to your question that says that this is not the proper solution, even though it solved the problem. I've managed to use `windeployqt` successfully before, so it is possible.