# Qt Application Deployment Problem in Windows

Tags: windows, qt, visual-c++, boost-asio

I am deploying a Qt application for Windows 10 and when I try to run it outside of Qt Creator I get an error (0xc000a200).

Based on my [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269825/windows-10-the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000a200) this looks like a windows 8+ specific error involving "AppContainers".

I have added `LTLINKOPTS = $(LTLINKOPTS) "/APPCONTAINER"` to my .pro file, and /APPCONTAINER to the LFLAGS in the makefile, neither has solved the issue.

Additionally, I did run windeployqt before this, and all qt dlls are present in the run directory.

.pro:

```
win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost/
    LIBS += -LC:/boost/stage/lib
    Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = ON
    LTLINKOPTS = $(LTLINKOPTS) "/APPCONTAINER"
}
```

Would really appreciate any guidance - this is my first windows Qt deployment.

Comment: The syntax of `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` looks like CMake syntax, not qmake so I am not sure it does anything here. So maybe you are missing Boost DLLs. Anyway, you can try to use a dependency checker like Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if you are missing any DLL.

Comment: Hi - it's not clear whether you're intending to distribute a package (msi style) or merely build a fully-contained image. If the latter, you need to build a static version of your program, which in turn requires a static version of Qt. If the former, you'll want to look at https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-creating-installers.html. If the latter, let me know, and I'll follow up with a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another day of working on this and I found the issue. Turns out it was a missing dll problem. Although I had used windeployqt it must have missed some important bits.

Once I copied all of the dlls in the Qt/5.13//bin directory into the deploy directory AND ran windeployqt the program ran properly.