# Convert Qt project into .exe file

Tags: qt, mingw, qt5, qt-creator

I want to convert a Qt project into .exe file so that I can run the application in any other Windows PC. How can I convert?
I use MinGW compiler for Qt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185974/deploying-qt-5-app-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is deploy your application. Qt projects generate a `.exe` that you can run locally because you've got the Qt libraries, so you need to distribute those to your end users. There's a good guide on the [Qt Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) on how to do this, and examples of the `windeployqt` tool that simplifies the process.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/22188918/5695504