# Making Standalone application from Qt project

Tags: qt, static

I searched every where and i tried many things but i didn't find a way to make a standalone application from my qt project , any ideas ?!

Will I need another application to do it or i will do it with Qt creator ?!

Comment: Do you mean compiling your application using static version of Qt or what? Could you please clarify?

Comment: @demonplus I want to convert the whole project to an exe file that runs it like any game ?

Comment: Don't you receive exe after compiling in Qt Creator? Is your platform Windows?

Comment: If you are on Windows, are you using VC++ or mingw? Have you searched "deploy qt app" on SO?

Comment: @demonplus no i don't mean that i want to make an exe file from the application like flash games for example tictactoe game

Comment: @JonHarper I'm on windows , i use qt creator and visual studio 2012 , can you explain what will i do ?

Comment: If you have compiled it succesfully with qt creator your .exe is already there .. just look around

Comment: @Marco i don't mean the file in the build or release folder i want to make an exe file that i can give to anyone to play the game

Comment: Have you tried to compile Qt source code statically?

Comment: Look here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html if you are in a hurry go straight to the end of the page

Comment: @lbarros just release it and i will find an exe file but that's not i wanted

Comment: @Marco That's exactly what i'm looking for thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy some necessary files into the executable's directory:

- `Qt5Core.dll`
- Any other Qt dlls you depend upon (Qt5Gui, Qt5Widgets, etc.)
- Create a subfolder called "plugins"
- Find `qtwindows.dll` in your "Qt/[release version]/[compiler version]/plugins" folder and copy it into the "plugins" folder you created.
- Run your executable.

Or:

Use `windeployqt.exe`. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185974/deploying-qt-5-app-on-windows) As @marco pointed out, the documentation for [windeployqt is here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html).

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Qt5 and not Qt4.

Comment: Thanks that's help to much :)

Answer (score 0):

For QT6: same response, but copy the directory <.../platforms> in the local  directory. There is no qtwindows.dll, and the .exe search in the <plugins/platforms> directory. With the whole directory it works fine. Solution worked also with QT5 on an other PC.