# Qt QML .exe file does not work on other computers

Tags: qt

The problem is that I can run my application correctly only on my computer (using .exe file). On the other computer, application runs (is on process list) but the window of appication does not appear. I have used Process Explorer to check which .dlls are needed and applied to that. Under the post is a screenshot with my files tree. I have used Everest - I checked OpenGl versions. On my computer it is 4.3.0 and the other - 4.0.0 (I read somewhere that it could have influence). I have Qt 5.6.0 version and I use MSVC 2013, 32bit, Windows 7. Application is wrote in QML. I have added msvc*.dll files and libEGL.dll file. What should I do, to be able to run the application on all computers with Win7? [image: Files tree part 1]

[image: Files tree part 2 (some jpgs. cut)]

EDIT: I wonder if that could help: this is the list of 8 dlls. which are needed to run application on my comupter and which are not "present" on the other computer. NIVIDIA, maybe OpenGl?
[image: Absynt on the other computer but needed part 1]

[image: Absynt on the other computer, but needed part 2]

Comment: Well, start the executable from a terminal (command line) and see the error output.

Comment: I have enter command to the console and as I had said - no errors, application appears in proccess list, application window does not appear on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run your Qt executable on any other computer you need to copy all the dependencies .dll files and QML or Qt Quick related files and the executable file should be present in the folder where we place all the dependencies. You can go through the below documentation:

https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows

I have also read that: Starting from Qt 5.2, there is `windeployqt` tool you can use. Just run it from command line to get help. But basic usage is, give it the .exe file, it will copy Qt dependencies to go with it. You can check the below post [Deploying Qt 5 App on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185974/deploying-qt-5-app-on-windows) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all library which use your app. To add library to project I suggest use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) by this program you can take list of all dependencies. In next step copy all items of the list to your application folder.