# Qt + QML app Windows deployment not working

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qml

I am trying to deploy a Qt (5.11.1) QML based application for windows platform. I am refering to this topic: [Deploying Qt 5 App on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185974/deploying-qt-5-app-on-windows#22217114). I used `windeployqt` tool on my executable in order to copy all necessary components. After that I kept on opening the executable in order to find out which dll's I am missing and gradually added one by one.

It this point my application runs and finishes at the same time without any information (as messagebox nor in command line). I know it works because passing the `-v` and `-h` parameters correctly show the version and help contents. Running the app without parameters should simply start the app and load `QML` part but it does not. I am out of ideas what else I might be missing. My deploy directory looks as follows at the moment:

```
03.09.2018  08:51    <DIR>          .
03.09.2018  08:51    <DIR>          ..
03.09.2018  08:44    <DIR>          audio
03.09.2018  08:44    <DIR>          bearer
11.03.2014  12:55         3 466 856 D3Dcompiler_47.dll
03.09.2018  08:44    <DIR>          iconengines
03.09.2018  08:44    <DIR>          imageformats
10.08.2018  23:38         3 385 870 isuaclient.dll
15.06.2018  16:54            22 016 libEGL.dll
29.12.2015  00:25           120 334 libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
15.06.2018  16:54         2 807 296 libGLESV2.dll
29.12.2015  00:25         1 540 622 libstdc++-6.dll
10.08.2018  23:39         1 989 409 libuastack.dll
29.12.2015  00:25            79 360 libwinpthread-1.dll
10.08.2018  23:39         1 497 744 libxml2.dll
03.09.2018  08:44    <DIR>          mediaservice
03.09.2018  08:18         2 182 158 ntm_client_win32.exe
14.06.2016  15:08        15 995 904 opengl32sw.dll
03.09.2018  08:44    <DIR>          platforminputcontexts
03.09.2018  08:47    <DIR>          platforms
03.09.2018  08:44    <DIR>          playlistformats
03.09.2018  08:44    <DIR>          qmltooling
03.09.2018  08:36         6 214 656 Qt5Core.dll
15.06.2018  16:59         6 490 624 Qt5Gui.dll
15.06.2018  17:55         1 011 712 Qt5Multimedia.dll
15.06.2018  16:57         1 806 848 Qt5Network.dll
15.06.2018  17:29         4 022 272 Qt5Qml.dll
15.06.2018  17:35         4 349 952 Qt5Quick.dll
15.06.2018  17:15           359 936 Qt5Svg.dll
15.06.2018  17:03         6 254 080 Qt5Widgets.dll
15.06.2018  16:55           216 064 Qt5Xml.dll
15.06.2018  17:22         3 515 904 Qt5XmlPatterns.dll
03.09.2018  08:51    <DIR>          QtGraphicalEffects
03.09.2018  08:50    <DIR>          QtQuick
03.09.2018  08:50    <DIR>          QtQuick.2
03.09.2018  08:44    <DIR>          styles
03.09.2018  08:44    <DIR>          translations
```

Running the application gives no traces:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\LukaszPrzenioslo\Desktop\deploy>ntm_client_win32.exe

C:\Users\LukaszPrzenioslo\Desktop\deploy>
```

Comment: Aren't there any logs?

Comment: Are you sure you passed correct arguments to `windeployqt`? Could you paste the whole commend?

Comment: What I did was `C:/<path to Qt>/windeployqt.exe my_executable.exe`. There are no traces at all in cmd line.

Comment: Then you're probably missing all your QML files, use `C:/<path to Qt>/windeployqt.exe --qmldir Path/To/Qml/Files my_executable.exe`.

Comment: I added them all manually next to the executable but will now try your suggestion

Comment: @Kaldrr you suggestion was correct, now it works. thank you.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio as the compiler, I like to open the VS command promp so it sets the windows SDK environment and then execute windeployqt from there, that way it also copies the windows redists and windows deps.